# Filling a Buffer by Mapping the Elements to Structure in Swift

Tags: swift, uiimage

I'm trying to fill a pixel buffer of an image with RGBA values by mapping an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>` to the following structure

```
struct Color {
    var red:CGFloat
    var green:CGFloat
    var blue:CGFloat
    var alpha:CGFloat
}
```

and then looping over the pixels

```
func fillImage (pixelData:UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, numBytes:Int) {
    var pixels = UnsafeMutablePointer<Color>(pixelData)
    let numPixels = Int(numBytes / sizeof(Color))
    for i in 0...numPixels-1 {
        pixels[i] = Color(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

I expected my image to be completely red, but the pixels are green instead. Moving the 1.0 to the green or blue position doesn't work either. I was able to set the pixel colors correctly one float at a time with `UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>(pixelData)`, but obviously it would be easier using the `Color` `struct`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On all 64-bit devices (e.g. iPhone 5s and later), `CGFloat` is 
a *64-bit* floating point number. If you want to create RGBA data with 
4-byte floating point values then you have to replace `CGFloat` by `Float`
in the color structure.